# I'm not able to find what is causing the segmentation error in my C++ code

Tags: arrays, gcc, g++

I have a C++ program where I have to rotate the array clockwise according to the given number of elements to be rotated (x). For example if the input array is

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

given that 2 elements (denoted as x) must to rotated.

The output array should be

```
[3,4,5,1,2]
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
   int t;
   cin>>t;
   while(t--){
       int n,x;
       cin>>n>>x;
       int a[n],b[x];
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
           cin>>a[i];
       }
      copy(a,a+x,b);
      copy(b,b+x,a+n);
      n=n+x;
      for(int i=x;i<n;i++){
          cout<<a[i]<<" ";
      }
   }
    return 0;
}
```

What I'm doing here is that I copy the given number of elements to a new array. Later copy them back to the original array starting from 'n'. So my array will look like [1,2,3,4,5,1,2].

Later I'm printing out the array starting from the index 'x'. So that my array will look like [3,4,5,1,2].

I'm able to compile the program and I'm getting the output. But while submitting the code in a website called GeekforGeeks its complier is throwing out a Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV).

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Isn't `copy(b,b+x,a+n)` asking to copy data after the *end* of the `a` array?

Comment: yes it is tadman

Comment: Hint: What do you think happens when you write outside of array bounds?

Comment: You need a compiler environment that has one, like Visual Studio Express, Xcode, or even Visual Studio Code + GCC or Clang. There's tons of options out there, those are just common examples.

Comment: wat if i first increase the array size and then the copy the elements?

Comment: Now you're on the right track. Also, as idclev points out consider using `std::vector` as we do in C++, since then you have a lot of easy resizing options not available if you're using C arrays.

Comment: @SaiDarshan No it's got nothing to do with array size. You approach is wrong, the copy statements don't execute a rotate.

Comment: @john You can rotate by duplicating, then taking a slice in the middle. it's a valid approach.

Comment: @tadman OK but inefficient, and I see no evidence that is what the OP is attempting.

Comment: @john  if memory is of no concern then it is actually rather efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
int a[n],b[x];
```

is not standard c++. See here for details: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) . Use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays.

Then here:

```
copy(a,a+x,b);
```

you use `x` but the size you used for `a` was `n` not `x`. Depending on your input this may acces the array out-of-bounds.

Next, here:

```
copy(b,b+x,a+n);
```

you try to copy to `a+n` but already `a+n` is beyond the last element of `a`. Arrays have fixed size, also `n=n+x;` wont help to change that.

To rotate elements of an array (or `std::vector`) you can use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

Comment: Yes i used size for a as n ..but in copy i need only starting 2 elements of array a.That is y im using a+x ..x contains the number of elements to rotate.If it is 2.I will only copy starting 2 elements of array "a"

Comment: @SaiDarshan not sure if I understand what you mean. In case you refer to what i wrote about `copy(a,a+x,b);` then I wrote this **may** acces the array out-of-bounds, doesnt mean that it does fail always. Still I would never write code like that, because it looks innocent but can easily fail with dramatic consequences (undefined behavior). Anyhow, `copy(b,b+x,a+n);` is definitely accessing out-of-bounds, `a` has `n` elements, not more

Comment: Yes i agree with the copy(b,b+x,a+n).What if i first increase the array size and then do this statement ?

Comment: @SaiDarshan arrays have fixed size, thats why I suggest to use `std::vector`

Comment: ok i m new to C++ programming can u link me a demo program how to use a vector please

Comment: @SaiDarshan here you can find some examples: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem 1

The line

```
  copy(a,a+x,b);
```

does not do what you want to do. It copies the first `x` elements of `a` to `b`, without an offset. If `x` is 2, that is equivalent to:

```
 b[0] = a[0];
 b[1] = b[1];
```

You need something that will do:

```
 b[0+x] = a[0];
 b[1+x] = a[1];

 ...

 b[n] = a[n-x-1];
```

To achieve that, you need to use:

```
 std::copy(a, a+(n-x), b+x);
```

#### Problem 2

The line

```
copy(b,b+x,a+n);
```

is notright.

1. You want to copy from `a` to `b`, not from `b` to `a`.
2. Using `a+n` immediately results in accessing the array using out-of-bounds indices, which causes undefined behavior.
3. The offsets used in that call don't make sense at all.

After the first line of `std::copy` is executed, you need something what will do the following:

```
 b[0] = a[n-x];
 b[1] = a[n-x+1];

 ...

 b[x-1] = a[n-1];
```

To achieve that, you need to use:

```
 std::copy(a+(n-x), a+n, b);
```

Answer (score -1):

Arrays must have determined size 
some compilers accept your code but other don't 
so try to use pointers instead